# Convert string to number in calculator

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, calculator, parseint

I am not a programmer by trade so please don't hold my simple question against me. I am sure the answer is simple, but I can't figure it out.

I am trying to design a mulch calculator to put on my company's website. My code appears to accept the input, but is returning a NaN value. It is obviously converting to info to a string as I expected. I have tried converting it back to a number by subtracting a 0 from my last variable and also using parseInt. Neither seemed to work. Would someone be willing to explain how to fix this issue, and why your solution worked. I am trying to understand what I did wrong.

See the code below.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Mulch Calculator</h1>

<form name="calcInput" id="calcInfoInput">

The length of the area you need to cover (in feet). <input type="text" name="length"
<br></br>
<br></br>
The width of the area you need to cover (in feet). <input type="text" `enter code here`name="width"
<br></br>
<br></br>
The depth of coverage you need (in inches). <input type="text" name="depth"
<br></br>
<br></br>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate Your Mulch Needs." onclick="processForm()" name="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Clear This Form.">

</form>
<script type ="text/javascript">


function processForm()
{
var allInfo = document.getElementById ("calcInfoInput");
var bedLength = allInfo.elements["length"].value;
var bedWidth = allInfo.elements["width"].value;
var bedDepthInches = allInfo.elements["depth"].value;
var squareFeet = bedLength * bedWidth;
var bedDepth = bedDepthInches / 12;
var cubicFeet = squareFeet * bedDepth;
var cubicYards = cubicFeet / 27;
//cubicYards = cubicYards-0;
//cubicYards = parseInt( cubicYards, 10 );
document.write('You will need at least '+ cubicYards +' cubic yards for your project.');
}

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: you need to spec `0` for the value of "empty" inputs. also, a type=number would provide nicer UX.

Comment: You can coerce your input values to integers either by prefixing `+` to them: `+allInfo.elements["length"].value` or by using `parseInt(allInfo.elements["length"].value, 10);`.

Comment: Thanks dandavis and Andy. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Dandavis, I like the type=number suggestion. I added it and it does improve the UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have fixed it!

Your problem turned out to be how you were getting the data from the input.

You used this:

```
var bedLength = allInfo.elements["length"].value;
```

I used this:

```
var bedLength = +allInfo["length"].value;
```

So essentially I removed the `.elements` for each place that you use the input values.

I also added:

```
calcscale = (calcscale).toFixed(3);
```

Which trims the decimal place to 3 ( so you dont get an answer like 3.111111111111111117 or something like that)!

```js
function calculate() {
  var allInfo = document.getElementById("calcInfoInput");
  var bedLength = +allInfo["length"].value;
  var bedWidth = +allInfo["width"].value;
  var bedDepthInches = +allInfo["depth"].value;
  var squareFeet = bedLength * bedWidth;
  var bedDepth = bedDepthInches / 12;
  var cubicFeet = squareFeet * bedDepth;
  var cubicYards = cubicFeet / 27;
  //cubicYards = cubicYards-0;
  //cubicYards = parseInt( cubicYards, 10 );
  output = (cubicYards).toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'You will need at least ' + output + ' cubic yards for your project.';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Mulch Calculator</h1>

  <form name="calcInput" id="calcInfoInput">

    The length of the area you need to cover (in feet).
    <input type="text" name="length" />
    <br>
    <br>The width of the area you need to cover (in feet).
    <input type="text" name="width" />
    <br>
    <br>The depth of coverage you need (in inches).
    <input type="text" name="depth" />
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
  <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Calculate You're Mulch Needs." onclick="calculate()" />
  <input type="reset" value="Clear This Form.">
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="result"></div>

  </form>


</body>
```

Comment: Trevor, thanks for the time you spent on this. I ran it and it looks great. You also fixed one of the next issues I was going to tackle by by shortening the numbers after the decimal.

Comment: Well if this solved your problem please press the checkmark next to my answer to accept it! Glad I could help!

Comment: Also... just so you know.. when you put this on your website or wherever, you will need to put the javascript back into your <script type ="text/javascript"> </script> tags.. as well as the <!DOCTYPE html>, <html>, and <head> tags!

Comment: The tagline in your profile says you like to help. You just proved that's true. Have a great day.

Comment: You as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your input values should be put through the parseInt() function with 10 as your radix and you should check that you don't get NaN with the isNaN(num). Javascript is loosely typed but that doesn't necessarily mean you can throw variables around through types without checking them.

Comment: `parseInt` is about the worst way to convert numbers in JS; slow to execute, relatively lots of code to type/read, it needs 2 arguments, it only produces ints, and yeah, that's enough reasoning...